# Reactjs: binding onClick to a dynamically created list component

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Say I have a render function that looks like this:

```
  render() {


    var user_rows = []
    this.state.user_list.forEach(function (user, index){
        user_rows.push(
              <tr key={user}>
              <td><div className="btn-toolbar"><button type="button" onClick={this.editUser.(usesr.sso)} className="btn btn-success-outline">Edit</button></div></td>
            </tr>)
    }) 

return (<tbody>
        {user_rows}
      </tbody>)
```

I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'editUser' of undefined

**I would like like the onClick to:**

**1.** Not run when the component is created, only run when actually clicked

**2.** bind to the function within this component properly

I tried:
`onClick={this.editUser.bind(null, user.sso)}`, but didn't seem to work in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you're facing as that the value of `this` inside of the callback passed to `.forEach` is not pointing to your React component class, but rather the global object.

Possible solutions:

1) Pass the correct value of `this` as the second argument to `.forEach`.

```
this.state.user_list.forEach(function (user, index) {
    // your code
}, this);
```

2) If you're using ES6, use an arrow function as your first argument to `.forEach`, which will automatically use the correct context.

```
this.state.user_list.forEach((user, index) => {
    // your code
});
```

An alternate approach to this problem would be to use the `.map` function to map each value in your array to some JSX that can be used in your `render()` function.

```
const user_rows = this.state.user_list.map(user => 
     <tr key={user}>
         <td>
             <div className="btn-toolbar">
                 <button type="button" onClick={this.edituser[user.sso]} className="btn btn-success-outline">Edit</button>
             </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
);
```

Comment: Just a side note: Instead of declaring a variable `user_rows` as an empty array and filling it using `.forEach`, you can achieve the same result using `.map` instead.  If you're curious as to how this would work, I can edit my answer to include a code snippet.

Comment: Hey Michael, that would be very useful to include! Thanks!

Comment: @ApathyBear Done!  Let me know if this doesn't make sense and I can try and clarify further.